# Como obtener un signed array en javascript como en Java (cipher and crypto-js)

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un problema con mi codigo de encriptacion de claves usando crypto-js.
por defecto genera un unsigned byte array (Uint8Array) y necesito pasarlo a signed byte array (Int8Array).
Este es mi codigo en JAvascript (Nodejs -typescript)

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// Encrypt
var plaintext = originalKey;
var pwhash = CryptoJS.SHA1(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(salt));
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(pwhash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).substr(0, 32));

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

var ciphertext = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

let uint8Array = new TextEncoder().encode(ciphertext);
console.log(uint8Array.toString());
```

//EXAMPLE RETURN

98,102,50,53,55,97,52,54,101,52,54,54,48,100,55,50,54,57,53,50,54,49,55,54,55,10 
1,50,49,100,98,48,102,51,56,52,98,49,53,53,53,48,97,99,52,55,97,53,49,100,98,48,55,56,52,52,102,48,99,48,57,101,53,49,102,51,97,100,53,51,53,101,99,100,48,48,48,53,100,98,57,99,57,52,98,53,99,57,99,53,53,49,53,52,54,55,100,98,99,99,99,101,48,99,101,54,55,97,56,52,52,56,97,54,54,55,101,48,52,49,100,102,54,102,49,48,54,99,99,55,48,102,98,51,51,52,102,53,50,55,51,97,48,51,55,48,99,53,100,52,98,99,51,54,48,99,100,97,100,52,97

Este es mi codigo en Java:

```
public byte[] crypto(String data) throws Exception {
    byte[] input = data.getBytes();
    byte[] keyBytes = CLIENT_KEY.getBytes();
    Log.d("CRYPTO",new String(keyBytes));
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
    //System.out.println(new String(input));
    //o.setText("Original: " + new String(input));

    // encryption pass
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
    //System.out.println(new String(cipherText));
    //e.setText("Encrypted: " + new String(cipherText));
    System.out.println("ENCRYPT: " + ctLength);

    return cipherText;
    //EXAMPLE RETURN:
    /*{57,-16,-30,34,-81,61,-14,-65,-1,83, -81, -78, 43, -26, -45, 77, 113, 
    -89, -91, -86, -11, -117, -28, -105, 45, 46, 103, 23, 11, -87, 86, -46, 
     -15, 52, 31, 11, -62, 115, 119, -56, 71, -125, -108, -41, -19, -116, 
    -76, 3, 97, 29, 77, 99, -33, 100, 41, 54, -2, 69, -50, 100, 41, -45, 54, 
    114, 8, 0, -111, 40, 103, -117, 0, -22, -20, 29, 107, 114, 45, -16, -85, 
    125}*/


}
```

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradezco!

Answer (score 2):

Todos los [`TypedArray` comparten el método `.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from), que permite transformar entre ellos:

```js
let u = Uint8Array.from([0,-1]); // -1 en un unsigned será 255
console.log('Sin signo', u);

let i = Int8Array.from(u); //255 en complemento a 2 vuele a ser -1
console.log('Con signo', i);
```

Comment: No me estaria funcionando... probe encriptando como lo hago en java pero no sucede nada